# SSRS Total Row minus a value based on another fields value

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, sum, conditional-statements

I am trying to get a total row displaying the sum of `P2_NUM_START` minus the count of records with a `PRODUCT_CODE` of "SWP" which will sometimes exist and sometimes not. Stripping out the IIF statement it constantly shows as False regardless of the existence of "SWP" what am I doing wrong?

Currently I am at:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!PRODUCT_CODE.Value ="SWP",Fields!P2_NUM_START.Value,0))
```

Comment: What do you mean it shows as false?   Do you mean zero (0)?

Comment: Yes it shows as zero. I had simplified it to show "No SWP" instead of zero and would display that every time.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want :
if PRODUCT_CODE of "SWP" then value will be 0 and if not then  sum of P2_NUM_START

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!PRODUCT_CODE.Value ="SWP",0,Fields!P2_NUM_START.Value))
```

Comment: This actually works IF there is no product Code of SWP then it correctly Sums all values in P2_NUM_START. If however there is a "SWP" it displays #Error in the cell.

Comment: =Sum(IIf(Fields!PRODUCT_CODE.Value ="SWP","0",Fields!P2_NUM_START.Value))

Comment: No change, still displays #Error. Nonetheless I was able to solve it via a different approach above.

Answer (score 0):

I actually Solved this from another approach. Adding the If condition to a calculated field in the data set and then calling that new field in a aggregate as follows:

If Condition in the calculated field called SWP_ACCT_TOTAL_P2

=IIF(Fields!PRODUCT_CODE.Value = "SWP", Fields!P2_NUM_START.Value,0)

Sum statement in the texbox

=Sum(Fields!P2_NUM_START.Value-Fields!SWP_ACCT_TOTAL_P2.Value)

Why this worked in separate statements but not in the SumIIF I do not know.